# Laravel how to query with Auth ID from another table

Tags: laravel

I have a `forms_table` where I query all my results for authenticated user with where `Auth::id()` in `user_id` column.

Each of these rows have a `boolean` column `alternation`. If this is 1, then it means there is a row in another table called `form_alternation` where I have the `Auth::id()`. This means the `Auth::id()` does not exist in the initial `forms_table`.

How can I retrieve the rows from the `forms_table` with where clause `where('user_id', Auth::id())` and show the rows where the `Auth::id()` exists in the `form_alternations`?

Currently I have this and it shows me 0 rows because the last `Auth::id()` clause.

```
   $baseQuery->with(['alternated' => function($q){
         $q->where('user_id', Auth::id());
      }]);
   $baseQuery->where('user_id', Auth::id());
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your table - it's a bit difficult to understand your logic

Comment: Do you have a relationship defined between `User` and `FormAlternation` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i see it you want your query to do something similar to this (in half pseudo code).

```
where (forms.user.id = Auth::id() OR (users.alternation = 1 AND alternated.user_id = Auth::id()))
```

This could be achieved with Eloquent, as i understand your domain, try something like this.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

// wrap it in where, to avoid other queries precedence ruining the or clause
$query->where(function (Builder $query) {
    // First part, where we assume user id is in forms
    $query->where('user_id', Auth::id());

    // Second part, check alternation or your relationship
    $query->orWhere(function (Builder $query) {
        $query->where('alternation', true);

        // Use whereHas to check if your forms has the user as a relationship
        $query->whereHas('alternated', function (Builder $query) {
            $query->where('user_id', Auth::id());
        });
    });
});
```

This should provide similar logic to the pseudo example, simply utilizing `orWhere()` logic and you can check relationships with `whereHas()`.

Comment: doesn't this query uses a lot memory on the wherehas? it will scan the entire database

Comment: Yes for larger datasets, for entry level Laravel this is the correct approach. If you have big tables, joining and filtering will probably give better performance.